# trying to select the last element of a navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select the last element of a navigation bar that could have x number of elements. I know that jquery selectors are arraylike objects, so I have tried using bracket notation to select the last element:

```
$(".navLinks")[$(".navLinks").length - 1].text();
```

This has not worked. Can anyone help me out with this? How do you select an element within a jquery selector and then attach a method to that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

```
$(".navLinks:last").text();
```

**Additional Information**

You can read up on all jQuery's selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
$('.navLinks:last').text();
```

will do it in a more convinient way.

Read more about [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".navLinks:last-child").text();
```

Comment: Be careful - `:last-child` can match multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) - use the `:last` selector. [More info here](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

```
$(".navLinks:last").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific type of element you're looking for, .last() may be what you need.  Here's an example with 'a'.

```
$(".navLinks a").last().addClass('myClass');
```